# How to add/keep Class<?> object inside a Parcelable class in Android Lollipop versions

Tags: android, class, parcelable, parcel

I am facing problem while sending `Parcelable` data from one `Activity` to another.

> **MY QUESTION:** Is it possible to add/keep `Class<?>` object inside a `Parcelable` class which has to be sent to another `Activity`? If possible then how can I achieve it?

I already tried doing it but I am getting the following exception in `Android 5.0, 5.1 and 5.1.1` versions:

**MY LOGCAT:**

```
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164): Process: com.example, PID: 31164
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.v2.BaseAct}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = java.lang.Class)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = java.lang.Class)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2384)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2203)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at com.example.template.HomeItemCls.readFromParcel(HomeItemCls.java:251)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at com.example.template.HomeItemCls.<init>(HomeItemCls.java:213)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at com.example.template.HomeItemCls$1.createFromParcel(HomeItemCls.java:260)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at com.example.template.HomeItemCls$1.createFromParcel(HomeItemCls.java:1)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2252)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2526)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1842)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2173)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:269)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.content.Intent.hasExtra(Intent.java:4879)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at com.example.v2.BaseAct.onCreate(BaseAct.java:184)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    ... 10 more
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.v2.fragment.SongListFragment
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.os.Parcel$2.resolveClass(Parcel.java:2370)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1641)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:657)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1512)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:755)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2378)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    ... 28 more
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.v2.fragment.SongListFragment
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164):    ... 38 more
04-14 14:58:36.838: E/AndroidRuntime(31164): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

**MY CODE:**

```
public class HomeItemCls implements Parcelable
{
    private Class<?> itemActivity;

    private Class<?> itemFragment;

    public Class<?> getItemActivity()
    {
        return itemActivity;
    }
    public void setItemActivity(Class<?> itemActivity)
    {
        this.itemActivity = itemActivity;
    }

    public void setItemFragment(Class<?> itemFragment)
    {
        this.itemFragment = itemFragment;
    }

    public Class<?> getItemFragment()
    {
        return itemFragment;
    }
    public HomeItemCls()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public HomeItemCls(Parcel in)
    {
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dest.writeValue(getItemFragment());
        dest.writeValue(getItemActivity());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setItemFragment((Class<?>) in.readValue(Class.class.getClassLoader()));
        setItemActivity((Class<?>) in.readValue(Class.class.getClassLoader()));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator()
    {
        public HomeItemCls createFromParcel(Parcel in)
        {
            return new HomeItemCls(in);
        }

        public HomeItemCls[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new HomeItemCls[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Class implements Serializable, you can try to use the pair writeSerializable/readSearializable. with readSerializable you have to cast to the specific type. You could also to change `Class<?> itemFragment;` to `Class<? extends Fragment> itemFragment;`

Comment: @Blackbelt ok i will give it a try

Comment: @Blackbelt : it didn't work. im getting the same exception.

Comment: can you update the question with the changes **without** changing  the original post?

Comment: you are not using writeSerializable and readSerializable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Class` implements `Serializable` not `Parcelable`, you cannot use `readValue` / `writeValue` pair (**these are `Parcelable` functions**).

So, you should use the pair `writeSerializable`/`readSerializable` (**these are `Serializable` functions**). Using `readSerializable` you have to cast the returned value to the specific type.

Optionally, You should also change

`Class<?> itemFragment;`

to

`Class<? extends Fragment> itemFragment;`,

and

`private Class<?> itemActivity;`

to

`private Class<? extends Activity> itemActivity;`